# How to use pcap_breakloop?

Tags: c, pcap

I have a pcap_loop function in another function, that captures packets
until the user stops it, i.e.

```
void functionA()
{
   signal(SIGINT, terminate_process); 
   pcap_loop(handle, -1, callback, NULL);
   ...

}

void terminate_process(int signum)
{
   pcap_breakloop(handle);
   pcap_close(handle);
}
```

Is it possible to set a duration for when packets would be captured? Something like:

```
if (time(NULL) - start_time > 100)
   pcap_breakloop(handle);
```

But I don't know where to put this, because so far all the examples I've seen used pcap_breakloop in a signal handler, which requires user intervention. How will the time condition be checked while pcap_loop is running?

Thank you.

Regards,
Rayne

Comment: I'm curious about the `handle` parameter you have passed to `pcap_breakloop()` in `terminate_process()`，how can you use it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [alarm](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/alarm.html) to generate a signal after a given number of seconds:

```
void functionA()
{
    signal(SIGALRM, terminate_process); 
    alarm(100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works in linux, but not in windows since SIGALRM does not exist.

Comment: @Rayne - unfortunately, I'm not an expert on the Windows API so don't know if there's something similar to `alarm`.  You can always start a thread that calls `Sleep` and then `pcap_breakloop`.