# Problems interrupting capture with libpcap

Tags: c++, c, signals, libpcap

Hi I'm doing a sniffer with c++ and libpcap and I would want to stop the capture when I press ctrl+c, this is my code:

```
void Capture::terminate_process(int s){
  pcap_breakloop(descr);
  pcap_close(descr);
}

void Capture::capturar(){
  signal(SIGINT, terminate_process);
  pcap_loop (descr, -1, mycallback, NULL);
}
```

At the .h I have declared:

```
 pcap_t *descr;
```

I've seen similar solutions for my problem like this: [How to use pcap_breakloop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377309/how-to-use-pcap-breakloop)
But I can't compile, I get this error:

**capture.cpp: 138:35: error: argument of type 'void (Capture ::) (int)' does not match '{aka __sighandler_t void (*) (int)}'**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`signal` requires a function pointer, you are using a member function pointer. Just declare `Capture::terminate_process(int)` as static:

```
class Capture {
public: 
    /* ... */
    static void Capture::terminate_process(int s);
    /* ... */
};

void Capture::terminate_process(int s){
  pcap_breakloop(descr);
  pcap_close(descr);
}
/* ... */
signal(SIGINT, &Capture::terminate_process);
```

You will have to make some changes to your code so that you don't depend on instance variables though.