# alarm() generates SIGALRM after random time

Tags: c++, linux, signals, libpcap

I am trying to make a program, that will parse pcap file until the timer expires. I use `alarm` function for that, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377309/how-to-use-pcap-breakloop?fbclid=IwAR3_MUvJ9BKkl-nvEIqCGkRWJ81UzBgq4H3Ejj5k9FFpb2jEfA6OYWhTgXc), which really stops the `pcap_loop`, but definitely not after given time.

Important parts of code:

```
pcap_t *handle;

void end_loop(int signum)
{
   pcap_breakloop(handle);
}

int main(...){
...
handle = pcap_open_live(argv[2], BUFSIZ, 1, 100, errbuf);
....
signal(SIGALRM, end_loop);
alarm(5);
pcap_loop(handle, num_packets, got_packet, NULL);
pcap_close(handle);
send_syslog_message(hostname, list_of_parsed_packets));
return 0;
}
```

I have tried running the program many times and it always stops, but as the title says, the time it takes is just random. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[`man pcap_breakloop`](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_breakloop.3pcap.html) says:

> The flag is checked in loops reading packets from the OS - a signal by itself will not necessarily terminate those loops - as well as in loops processing a set of packets returned by the OS. **Note that if you are catching signals on UNIX systems that support restarting system calls after a signal, and calling pcap_breakloop() in the signal handler, you must specify, when catching those signals, that system calls should NOT be restarted by that signal. Otherwise, if the signal interrupted a call reading packets in a live capture, when your signal handler returns after calling pcap_breakloop(), the call will be restarted, and the loop will not terminate until more packets arrive and the call completes.**

This is probably what you observes. The alarm signal is received in due time, but you fail to specify that system calls should NOT be restarted by that signal. As a consequence, `pcap_loop()` is not returning immediately.

See [How to know if a Linux system call is restartable or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13357019/5470596)

Comment: It seems that this is the problem. However this is the first time I am using signals and I am not sure if I am able to make it work. My only idea, after reading this, is to set global flag in `end_loop` and in `got_packet` call `pcap_breakloop` if flag is set.